# how do I end a dplyr pipe with NULL? to allow easy comment/uncomment

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  NULL
```

Do you remember the cool trick ending your ggplot commands with `NULL` to allow the easy commenting/uncommenting of lines within your code? Compare the chunk above to the chunk below. In this example I'll comment out `theme_classic() +` and my code still works fine, since `NULL` is at the end.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  # theme_classic() + 
  NULL
```

OK. So how do I do the same thing with a dplyr pipe? I want to put the `NULL` at the end so I could comment/uncomment the `count(cyl)` at will. But it doesn't quite work. I get an `Error in .() : could not find function "."`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  NULL

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # count(cyl) %>% 
  NULL
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `... %>% print()` at the end?

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, I think I've seen `I()` used for ending dplyr chains.

Comment: @aosmith I believe you should post it as an answer, it's the first time I see that trick and it might be usefull to others in the future, SO's main goal.

Comment: @AntoniosK The previous comment is also valid for your `print()` suggestion.

Comment: also `identity()` works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've seen `I()` ("asis") used for this (I think on twitter, but can't seem to re-find the conversation):

```
mtcars %>% 
     as_tibble() %>% 
     # count(cyl) %>% 
     I()
```

Note that using `I()` prepends the class `"AsIs"` on the object.  There is a possibility that this could lead to unintended consequences if using the assigned object in some later step.

Other possibilities from comments that all appear to work without the `I()` side effect:
`identity()` or `force()`
`print()` or `{.}` or `return()`

Comment: or `force` or `identity` as their code really is `function(x) x`

Comment: possible also to use `{.}`. `I` changes the class of the object, which might have unintended consequences if the output is assigned